# Rails 5: Couldn't find Comment without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error when I click on the `edit` or 'delete' link : `Couldn't find Comment without an ID`

with the following setup:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_item
before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update, :comment_owner]
before_action :comment_owner, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

  def create
    @comment = @item.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else
      render 'comment'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to item_path(@item)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:content))
      redirect_to item_path (@item)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_owner
    unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id
      flash[:notice] = "You shall not pass!"
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  def find_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
  end

  def find_comment
    @comment = @item.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

app/views/comment/comment.html.erb

```
This Item has<%= pluralize(@comments.count, "Connect") %>


<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><strong><%= comment.user.username %></strong></p>
    <%= comment.content %>

    <% if current_user == comment.user %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_comments_path(comment.item, comment) %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete Comment', item_comments_path(comment.item, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for([@item, @item.comments.build]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, id: :content %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb if I do `rake routes | grep comment`

```
 item_comments GET    /items/:item_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
               POST   /items/:item_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_item_comment GET    /items/:item_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
 edit_item_comment GET    /items/:item_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
 item_comment GET    /items/:item_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
             PATCH  /items/:item_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
              PUT    /items/:item_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
            DELETE /items/:item_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_comments_on_item_id"
    t.index ["shopper_id"], name: "index_comments_on_shopper_id"
  end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :user
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: have you tried changing `item_comments_path(comment.item, comment)` to just `item_comments_path(comment)` since a `comment` belongs to `item` it should be able to determine `item_id` and `id` from the comment. additionally you could make this `item_comments_path(comment.item_id, comment.id)`

Comment: Please do `rake routes | grep comment` from the command line and post the result in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @moveson! Please check `routes.rb` for the results, I just updated it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @engineersmnky! If I change to this: `item_comments_path(comment)` it returns this: `Couldn't find Comment without an ID`.. If I change to this: `item_comments_path(comment.item_id, comment.id)` it returns this: `Couldn't find Comment without an ID`

Comment: Your routes file is incorrect then the routes should be like `/items/:item_id/comments/:id/edit`. I just reviewed your previous post (prior to revision) and it looks like your issue is that you are missing the `s` on `resources` for `comments`. it says `resource :comments` where it should be `resources :comments`

Comment: @ engineersmnky, the edit works with this: `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_comment_path(comment.item_id, comment.id) %>` and the delete returns this: `No route matches [DELETE] "/items/6/comments.4"` with this: `<%= link_to 'Delete Comment', item_comments_path(comment.item_id, comment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Comment: Did you make the change I recommended? your issue is that it is interpreting the second argument as the format (eg. `html`,`json`,`xml` or in your case `4`)

Comment: Yes I did change the routes to `resources :comments`

Comment: add your updated out put from `rake routes` as well as your route file. your routes should resemble [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: `DELETE` is for a specific `comment` so it would be `item_comment_path` (not pluralized) look at your routes and you will understand

Comment: I just updated the `routes.rb` with new `routes`.

Comment: Thanks @ engineersmnky it works... I had to change to `item_comment_path'

Answer (score 1):

Each ActiveRecord's table should have primary key but "comments" does not.

**Option 1 (Rails way)**

Use primary key (add id field to comments table).

**Option 2**

Use composite primary key (see https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys)

Comment: `id` is not shown in the migration files it is implied

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is with this line

```
<%= form_for([@item, @item.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

`@item.comments.build` adds a new (not database persisted) comment, then you save it into `@comments` and render in cycle. So

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_comments_path(comment.item, comment) %>
```

Appears on the page as

```
<a href="/items/1/comments//edit">Edit</a>
```

I advise you to try to change

```
<%= form_for([@item, @item.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for([@item, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
```

Also could you please confirm that there is a broken - without a comment ID 
- link to edit/delete comment on the page?

Comment: The comment is `saved` in the `create` action and thus receives an `id` this is purely a routing issue. `build` simply adds the `item_id` to the initialized comment where as `Comment.new` does not. essentially `build` is equivalent to `Comment.new(item_id: item.id)`

Comment: @engineersmnky I think that `@item.comments.build` adds not a persisted record to `@comments`. And then this comment without an ID is being rendered. Btw, we do not neeed `item_id` for comment when constructing `form_for([@item, Comment.new])`

Comment: `@comments` is rendered first and either way is not a direct reference to `@item.comments` but rather a copy.  You are correct that you do not need it as it will create the same but in this case the issue was a few simple typographical errors `resource :comments` should have been `resources :comments` and `item_comments_path` should have been `item_comment_path`.